# Triangle inequality in difference form

Tags: geometry

Suppose the weights of $3$ boys are such that the sum of the weights of any two boys is greater than the third boy.

From above info can we conclude that the weight of any boy is greater than the difference in weights of the other two boys?

I know triangle inequality gives that. But the boys example doesn't look obvious to me... Is there any other way to get convinced of this? (w/o using triangle inequality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the three weights are $a \le b \le c$.

Then from
$$c<a+b$$
you can subtract $b$ on both sides to get
$$c-b<a$$
Similarly you can prove the other inequalities.